# How to groupby and then aggregate on multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue, pyspark-pandas

I am using Pandas on Spark. I need to groupby A and B and then aggregate to return a list of map where keys are C and values are D
Sample input:

```
         A      B        C           D
0        7 201806851 0006378110  2223982011
1        7  6378110 0006378110  2223982011
2        7 201806851  201806851  20972475011
3        7  6378110  201806851  20972475011
```

Sample output:

```
         A      B        C
0        7  6378110 [[0006378110, 2223982011], [201806851, 20972475011]]
1        7 201806851 [[0006378110, 2223982011], [201806851, 20972475011]]
```

This is my code. It's giving the error, `assert len(key) == len(that_column_labels) AssertionError` on the first line. Any idea?

```
seed_data["C"] = seed_data[["C", "D"]].to_dict('records')
seed_data = (seed_data
                     .groupby(["A", "B"])["C"]
                     .apply(list).reset_index(name="C"))
```

Tried a few things, like extracting columns C and D into a separate dataframe, convert to dict and then using it as an aggregate column. But getting assertion error.

Answer (score 0):

This operation can be done in an efficient manner using the native spark functions. In pyspark, you need to group the dataframe then collect the list of pairs of `c -> D`

```
df.groupBy('A', 'B').agg(F.collect_list(F.create_map('C', 'D')).alias('CD'))
```

---

```
+---+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|A  |B        |CD                                                      |
+---+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|7  |201806851|[{0006378110 -> 2223982011}, {201806851 -> 20972475011}]|
|7  |6378110  |[{0006378110 -> 2223982011}, {201806851 -> 20972475011}]|
+---+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Getting this error, "ValueError: aggs must be a dict mapping from column name to aggregate functions (string or list of strings)."

Comment: @WorkInProgress Can you please make sure that `df` is a actual pyspark dataframe and not a pandas on spark dataframe.